# How do you change the presented view of an SKScene?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I've checked out the class reference and a couple of other S.O. posts and can't seem to get my scene the way I need it. From what I've found thus far, one can set the `SKScene.size` property to some `CGSize` and the view will display the SKScene of that size. However, when I change the value of the `size` property, my visuals don't change a bit on my device's screen.

I've created an SKShapeNode as my "world" and set its size to be 7000 Units by 7000 Units

```
world = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSizeMake(7000, 7000))
```

and when I load the scene, only a small portion of the world is displayed, as expected.

I know this would be disproportionate to the screen's height and width, but for simplicity's sake, how would one change the SKScene to display the entire 7000 by 7000 world in the device's screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to alter the scene's `size` in this manner. Creating a scene of 7000*7000 points would have a Retina iPad render 98 megapixels 60 times per second. Ouch.

#### Scale a child node

Simply create a new SKnode `sceneContents` and add your SKShapeNode as a child to this node. When you wish to "zoom", scale down the `sceneContents` node (through the `xScale` and `yScale` properties of SKNode). You can use SKAction for this, so it's nice and smooth.

#### SKCameraNode

If you can move to iOS 9, I would recommend looking into [SKCameraNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKCameraNode/). This is still in beta at the moment but it works nicely.
Simply create an SKCameraNode, add it to the scene and set it to be the camera for the scene.

```
SKCameraNode *camera = [SKCameraNode new];
[self.scene addChild:camera];
self.scene.camera = camera;
camera.xScale = 10.f;
camera.yScale = 10.f;
```

Hm, I should learn Swift at some point. Nevertheless, the concept should be clear. You can use SKAction to manipulate the camera node with an animation.